# No instance of constructor C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have a problem.

> "IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "Tree::Tree" matches the
>   argument list argument types are:  (float [3], float [3], float,
>   float, int, double, int, int)".

Third line:

```
float ColorS[3]={1,1,1},ColorF[3]={1,0,0};
for(unsigned int i=0;i<20;i++){
    Tree a(ColorS,        ColorF,
           5.0f,          5.0f,
           rand()%180+90, 0.67,
           rand()%4+2,    rand()%6+2);
    las.push_back(a);
    a.cordx=rand()%50-25;
    a.cordz=rand()%50-25;
}
```

Thats my class in Tree.h:

```
class Tree{
.
.
.
Tree(float [3],float [3],float,float,float,int,int);
.
.
.
};
```

And thats my construcotor in Tree.cpp:

```
Tree::Tree(float fromColor[3], float toColor[3], 
           float h=5.0f,       float angle=60*rad,
           float ratio=0.67f,  int amount=4, 
           int maxLevel=5){
.
.
.
```

===

Edit: Now I have this problem:

> 'Tree::Tree' : no overloaded function takes 5 arguments

Second line:

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<20;i++){
Tree a(5.0f,   1.0f,
       0.67f,   rand()%4+2,
       rand()%6+2);
    las.push_back(a);
    a.cordx=rand()%50-25;
    a.cordz=rand()%50-25;
}
```

That's my class in Tree.h:

```
class Tree{
    ...
    Tree(float,float,float,int,int);
    ...
};
```

And thats my construcotor in Tree.cpp:

```
Tree::Tree(float h=5.0f,       float angle=60*rad,
           float ratio=0.67f,  int amount=4, 
           int maxLevel=5){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've reformatted your code - you can see that you're calling a constructor with 8 parameters and the declaration has 7

Comment: I've reedited your question include the original problem and the new one. Remember the answers will make no sense if the question is completely different. You need to have some context for someone reading the Q&A in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the constructor with 8 parameters

```
Tree a(ColorS,        ColorF,
       5.0f,          5.0f,
       rand()%180+90, 0.67,
       rand()%4+2,    rand()%6+2);
```

But you declared it with  7

```
Tree::Tree(float fromColor[3], float toColor[3], 
           float h=5.0f,       float angle=60*rad,
           float ratio=0.67f,  int amount=4, 
           int maxLevel=5){
```

This is a primary reason to not have terse code. You should have lots of whitespace so that things like this become obvious. You might also (I don't know if it's valid though in your case) to have better names for the parameters like `h`. Also I tend to find the code like this is easier to read:

```
const float defaultH = 5.0f;
const float defaultAngle = 5.0f;
const float ratio = rand() % 180 + 90f;
const float amount = 0.67;
const float maxLevel = 5.0f;

Tree a(ColorS,     ColorF,
       defaultH,   defaultAngle,
       ratio,      amount ,
       rand()%4+2, maxLevel);
```

**Edit: Since you've changed your question considerably**

Now you can see what you're passing and where, and thus parameter type issues are more visible such as amount being declared as an `int` and being passed as a `float`. This is why I made the suggestion to use the above technique to make your code less opaque.

Have you recompiled all the code?

Comment: Thx, that was true. But i changed my code little bit and still have an issue.

Comment: READ your code. Are you passing the same parameter types? Note what I said in my last sentence

Answer (score 0):

You have passed the wrong number of arguments to your constructor.

For constructors or methods with a long number of arguments, you may want to type each one on their own line, to improve readability and avoid mistakes like this.